# убрать всплывающую подсказку при наведении на ссылку

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Как убрать всплывающую подсказку ссылки при наведении на саму ссылку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пример, что за подсказка то?

Comment: вы хотите убрать title?

Comment: @GGO обновил пост

Comment: ее никак не убрать, это функция в хроме прописана, но если вы про #header-01, то нужно навесить click и в колбек передать event и прописать event.preventDefault(); Пример: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault, но есть ряд нюансов, все зависит от задачи.

Comment: @GGO, `event.preventDefault()` отменит переход к якорю.

Answer (score 5):

убрать атрибут `href` у ссылки, а переход реализовать яваскриптом по клику.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант про который написал [@Инквизитор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1148307/221218), написанный на jQuery.

```js
$('[data-href]').on('click', function(){
  let href = $(this).attr('data-href') || false;
  if(href !== false) location.href = href;
});
```

```css
[data-href] { /* "имитируем" стили дефолтной ссылки */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="https://google.com">Обычная ссылка</a> - которая показывается ссылку в нижней части браузера</p>
<p><span data-href="https://google.com">Необычная ссылка</span> - которая уже не отобразит ничего, но при этом выполнит переход</p>
```